# passing by reference won't work in php

Tags: php, pass-by-reference

i was about to make a filter helper and to just test my idea by basic replacing function using passing by reference and it won't work!

```
<?php
$text ="hello world i am here !";

 function findandreplace(&$text, $search, $replaced)
 {

    return str_replace($search, $replaced, $text);

 }

print findandreplace($text,'e','E');
print "<br>";
print $text;
```

the output is always like that :

```
hEllo world i am hErE !
hello world i am here !
```

i tried may things but i won't work, so what is my fault.

Comment: Why bother returning $text if you're using pass by reference?.... but `str_replace()` itself isn't pass by reference, it returns the modified value

Comment: i tried using return and then i omtt it, it won't work neither , but without return , it was giving an Notice [ Notice: Only variable references should be returned by reference ]

Answer (score 4):

You are not making any changes to the passed `$text` string, since [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) does not modify the passed in string - it receives a copy of the passed in value, and returns the result. It 
If you assign the result of `str_replace` to the `$text` variable, it will work as expected:

```
 $text ="hello world i am here !";

 function findandreplace(&$text, $search, $replaced)
 {

    $text =  str_replace($search, $replaced, $text); //<-- now it will work
    return $text;

 }

print findandreplace($text,'e','E');
print "<br>";
print $text;
```

Comment: Why return something that was passed by reference? I know it came from OP's code but still isn't that redundant?

Comment: @HankyPanky yes it is redundent, i expect the OP added the return so he could run the 'test' - comparing the output with the initial referenced variable.

Comment: That could then easily change to printing `$text` first then call the function then print `$text` again at least in this answer cause because it nicely explains the error by OP

Comment: @HankyPanky Also true, maybe i should make an edit noting that for any future visitors

Comment: Thanks @Steve it blows my mind , and i added return as i have notice error when remove it [Notice: Only variable references should be returned by reference ]